# Implement Jquery show()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to combine JQuery.show() whit mine working animation so I can display text.

I would like to achieve the same effect like here on this [working example](http://www.mattconnolly.com/Examples/CircleJQuery/test-circle.html) .But I don't want to use "data" prefix for displaying text, I want to use jquery.show(). I am having trouble understanding where and how to put mine text for each button and showing it on the middleBubble.

Only difference between mine example and this one, is that mine middleBubble is toggling.

How can I make this work's and implement jquery show() library in working animation?

HTML for mine example:

```
 <section class='circle-animation'>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-pull-1">
            <div id="middlepapir" class="jumbotron">
              <div class="row">

                <img class="papir img-responsive" src="img/circle/11.png" alt="">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="move1 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-push-4"> 
                      <a href="#"><img class="position1 round" src="img/circle/off/home-all-icon-off.png"></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="move2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-push-1">
                      <a href="#"><img class="position2 round" src="img/circle/off/home-cover-icon-off.png"></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="move3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-push-7">
                      <a href="#"><img class="position3 round" src="img/circle/off/home-design-icon-off.png"></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="move4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                      <a href="#"><img class="position4 round" src="img/circle/off/home-diy-icon-off.png"></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="move5 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-push-8">
                      <a href="#"><img class="position5 round" src="img/circle/off/home-marketing-icon-off.png"></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="move6 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-push-1">
                      <a href="#"><img class="position6 round" src="img/circle/off/home-other-icon-off.png"></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="move7 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-push-4">
                      <a href="#"><img class="position7 round" src="img/circle/off/home-special-icon-off.png"></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="move8 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-push-7">
                      <a href="#"><img class="position8 round" src="img/circle/off/home-vip-icon-off.png"></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>   
          </div>  
        </div>  
      </div>    
    </div>
  </section>
```

Jquery for HTML section:

```
// jQuery script for are Circle div whit Scroll Reveal Script

$(document).ready(function(){
    /*==========================================
    SCROLL REVEL SCRIPTS
    =====================================================*/
    window.scrollReveal = new scrollReveal();
    /*==========================================
    WRITE  YOUR  SCRIPTS BELOW
    =====================================================*/
    $('.round').click(function(){
       $('.papir').animate({
        width: ['toggle', 'swing'],
        height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
       }); 
    });    

});
```

Comment: you will need to pair each button and text using ids , based on a button id you show the text by selecting the corespondent id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more difficult to examine without your CSS, however, it seems that you missed the layout that your example used.  They have a separate area for the main text called id="middleBubble".  This is the area that the text is being replaced in.

They are performing the replacement here:

```
$("#middleBubble").html("<p><b>" + $(this).data("bubble1") + "</b><br />" + $(this).data("bubble2") + "</p>");
```

where "this" is the element (in this case the image) that has been hovered over.  The data is stored in the data-bubble1 and data-bubble2 attributes.  You could store it there (the replacement text for each section) or you could store it as a keyed JSON object and use the id of the image to key which values to use.  I would recommend the later, but to each their own.

Comment: Thank you, I will figure it eventually,  I just didn't want to use replacement id, mine layout fits everything in one div, and I have used bootstrap grid sistem to position the buttons.